# Python and Pandas trouble with hex to number conversion

Tags: python, pandas, hex, python-2.x

This might be something really stupid as I've been away from python for 10 years.

I'm applying the following function on a pandas dataframe named rebal which has several columns containing hex string data;

```
def hex2page(s, pagesize=1):
    if(s[:2]=='0x'): 
        i=long(s,16)*pagesize
        #print(s, i)
        return i
    return None
```

Here is a successful run you can see a new column 'Allocated' with the direct conversion to decimal (at the far right);

```
rebal['Allocated']=rebal['Alc_PG'].apply(hex2page)
rebal.head()

            Time Stamp       LOG  POOL  Cap T_DEVNum E_DEVNum    HDEV   Alc_PG   T_MVPG   E_MVPG     0DPG       Hist  Allocated
0  2013/08/20 08:51:50  00642fff     0  ---      ---      ---  0x7c8a      ---      ---  0x0000d  0x00000    DPV END        NaN
1  2013/08/20 08:51:50  00642fff     0  ---      ---      ---  0x7c8b  0x002e0  0x0008d      ---      ---  DPV START        736
2  2013/08/20 08:51:47  00642ffe     0  ---      ---      ---  0x7c89      ---      ---  0x00018  0x00000    DPV END        NaN
3  2013/08/20 08:51:47  00642ffe     0  ---      ---      ---  0x7c8a  0x002b6  0x0000d      ---      ---  DPV START        694
4  2013/08/20 08:51:40  00642ffd     0  ---      ---      ---  0x7c89  0x002a0  0x00018      ---      ---  DPV START        672
```

So it works on column Alc_PG.  But if I try another column with the same format of string it fails returning zero for every hex string;

```
rebal['T_MVPG'].apply(hex2page)

0    NaN
1      0
2    NaN
3      0
4      0
5    NaN
```

But if I uncomment the #print in the above function it prints the correct conversion;

```
('0x0008d', 141L)
('0x0000d', 13L)
('0x00018', 24L)
('0x00070', 112L)
('0x00073', 115L)
('0x00011', 17L)
('0x00062', 98L)
```

So I'm very confused.  I've even had prints in there to check types and the s is definitely entering the function as a str.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
rebal[0:5].to_dict()

{'0DPG': {0: '0x00000', 1: '---', 2: '0x00000', 3: '---', 4: '---'},
 'Alc_PG': {0: '---', 1: '0x002e0', 2: '---', 3: '0x002b6', 4: '0x002a0'},
 'Allocated': {0: nan, 1: 736.0, 2: nan, 3: 694.0, 4: 672.0},
 'Cap': {0: '---', 1: '---', 2: '---', 3: '---', 4: '---'},
 'E_DEVNum': {0: '---', 1: '---', 2: '---', 3: '---', 4: '---'},
 'E_MVPG': {0: '0x0000d', 1: '---', 2: '0x00018', 3: '---', 4: '---'},
 'HDEV': {0: '0x7c8a', 1: '0x7c8b', 2: '0x7c89', 3: '0x7c8a', 4: '0x7c89'},
 'Hist': {0: 'DPV END',
  1: 'DPV START',
  2: 'DPV END',
  3: 'DPV START',
  4: 'DPV START'},
 'LOG': {0: '00642fff',
  1: '00642fff',
  2: '00642ffe',
  3: '00642ffe',
  4: '00642ffd'},
 'POOL': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'T_DEVNum': {0: '---', 1: '---', 2: '---', 3: '---', 4: '---'},
 'T_MVPG': {0: '---', 1: '0x0008d', 2: '---', 3: '0x0000d', 4: '0x00018'},
 'Target': {0: nan, 1: 141.0, 2: nan, 3: 13.0, 4: 24.0},
 'Time Stamp': {0: '2013/08/20 08:51:50',
  1: '2013/08/20 08:51:50',
  2: '2013/08/20 08:51:47',
  3: '2013/08/20 08:51:47',
  4: '2013/08/20 08:51:40'}}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the code where `hex2page` is called.

Comment: Seems to work fine here, which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: It's being run in an ipython notebook so the code is as above.

Comment: Version of pandas is 11.0, part of latest anaconda.

Comment: @user2713369 can you edit to include the column: rebal['T_MVPG']

Comment: Please also post `rebal['T_MVPG'].dtype`.

Comment: The column is there Andy next to Alc_PG (scroll to the right) I've tried the same function on columns HDEV - it works ok but T_MVPG and E_MVPG both return 0 for all hex values but work okay when printed.  Weird.  I think I might pull it out of the notebook and try a standalone script.

Comment: @user2713369 yes, but when I do this (by copy and pasting the DataFrame you give) it works! so there is something fishy going on. Outputing the column might help, or include the output of `rebal.to_dict()`, maybe both

Comment: Okay so it's something to do with Anaconda ipython notebook environment as it works from a script...

Comment: Maybe I should mention that rebal has 262144 rows.  Runing to_dict on the whole dataframe crashes the notebook, but not the kernel.  I've pasted a subset to_dict above and it looks okay so I suspect related to memory management somewhere.

Comment: I just did this again after killing old kernels and notebooks from a new separate notebook and it worked fine.  So I restarted and loaded my original notebook and went through executing each command and again this time it worked so it looks like I screwed something up in the original kernel session.  - Basically I cannot recreate it.  Sorry all for wasting time but I've learned an important lesson - if at first it doesn't work try again - but in a new session.

Comment: @mrkbutty Just a sidenote: Anaconda updated the version of Pandas to 0.12. You just have to run `conda update pandas` in your terminal, and you'll get the new version.